# Matlab Differ between -- and - when changing LineStyle

Tags: matlab, string-comparison

I've a program where I want to be able to change the linestyle by an input but I'm having some trouble changing from - to -- and from -- to -. it gives the 'The choosen style is already used' message, how can I make the program see the difference between them without having to write the -- spaced like - -?

```
 style=input('Give new style ( :, --, -., -): ','s');
  h(id) = plot_handles(id);

if get(h(id), 'LineStyle')==(style)
    disp('The choosen style is already used!');
else
set(h(id), 'LineStyle', style); 

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `==`, you will get a piece-for-piece, comparison, as you can see below:

```
'-' == '--'    
ans =    
     1     1
```

Try using `isequal` instead:

```
isequal('-' ,'--')
ans =
     0
```

I think this should work:

```
if isequal(get(h(id), 'LineStyle'), (style))
    disp('The choosen style is already used!');
else
set(h(id), 'LineStyle', style);
```